# Debian: Confusing ld.so manpage documentation

Tags: debian, ld.so.conf

I am starring at the `ld.so` manpage on my Debian stable system. [It currently states](https://manpages.debian.org/bullseye/manpages/ld.so.8.en.html#Hardware_capabilities):

```
$ man ld.so
[...]
NOTES
   Hardware capabilities
       Some shared objects are compiled using hardware-specific instructions which do not exist on every CPU.  Such objects should be installed in directories whose names define the required hardware ca‐
       pabilities, such as /usr/lib/sse2/.  The dynamic linker checks these directories against the hardware of the machine and selects the most suitable version of a given shared object.  Hardware capa‐
       bility directories can be cascaded to combine CPU features.  The list of supported hardware capability names depends on the CPU.  The following names are currently recognized:
```

What surprises me is the last sentence:

> The following names are currently recognized

That is currently not true (or at least not anymore), since all I can find is this:

```
% cat /etc/ld.so.conf.d/*
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfakeroot
# Multiarch support
/usr/local/lib/i386-linux-gnu
/lib/i386-linux-gnu
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu
/usr/local/lib/i686-linux-gnu
/lib/i686-linux-gnu
/usr/lib/i686-linux-gnu
# libc default configuration
/usr/local/lib
# Multiarch support
/usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
# Legacy biarch compatibility support
/lib32
/usr/lib32
# Legacy biarch compatibility support
/libx32
/usr/libx32
```

Is it true that `ld.so` will magically find a library in -say- `/usr/lib/sse2/` on my machine ?

Reference:

```
% apt-cache policy manpages
manpages:
  Installed: 5.10-1
  Candidate: 5.10-1
  Version table:
 *** 5.10-1 500
        500 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

---

For completeness here is the same output from a bullseye 32bits chroot:

```
% cat /etc/ld.so.conf.d/*
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libfakeroot
# Multiarch support
/usr/local/lib/i386-linux-gnu
/lib/i386-linux-gnu
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu
/usr/local/lib/i686-linux-gnu
/lib/i686-linux-gnu
/usr/lib/i686-linux-gnu
# libc default configuration
/usr/local/lib
```

Comment: hmm, it says "The following names are currently recognized: x86 **(32-bit only)**: ..." and doesn't mention 64-bit systems at all. Also, I think some of that stuff (cmov, i686, sse2(?)) are always available on amd64. Then again, you do have `i386` mentioned in the output of `apt-cache`, but do you actually have 32-bit packages installed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The following is based on glibc based system (before 2.37 release)

Yes, it will, but since you’re on x86, only for 32-bit binaries. See for example `libspeex1` [which ships](https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/i386/libspeex1/filelist) its library in `/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/` (for all 32-bit x86 systems) and `/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/sse2/` (for SSE2-capable 32-bit x86 systems). Another example is `libx264-160` [which ships](https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/i386/libx264-160/filelist) its library in `/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/` and `/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/sse2/` (for SSE2-capable i686-compatible 32-bit x86 systems).

This doesn’t rely on listing the capability-related directories in `ld.so.conf` etc.; `ld.so` looks for *sub*directories of directories on its search path. If you run

```
/sbin/ldconfig -v 2>/dev/null | grep -A3 hwcap
```

you’ll see the capability-related directories which are used on your system (*i.e.* they contain libraries and `ldconfig` knows about them).

Another trick (works with 2.37 glibc) to find the search paths is as follow:

```
% LD_DEBUG=libs LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. /bin/true
   3626040:     find library=libc.so.6 [0]; searching
   3626040:      search path=./glibc-hwcaps/x86-64-v3:./glibc-hwcaps/x86-64-v2:.                (LD_LIBRARY_PATH)
```

Comment: Do you know where the value `hwcap` is documented ?

Comment: I’m not sure it is…

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the help from @stephen-kitt, I discover there are also some undocumented "subfolders" on x86_64.

Eg:

```
$ sudo mkdir /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/haswell
$ sudo mkdir /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/avx512_1
$ sudo cp /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libx264.so.160 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/haswell
$ sudo cp /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libx264.so.160 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/avx512_1
$ sudo ldconfig
% sudo ldconfig -p | grep hwcap
        libx264.so.160 (libc6,x86-64, hwcap: 0x0004000000000000) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/haswell/libx264.so.160
        libx264.so.160 (libc6,x86-64, hwcap: 0x0000000000000004) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/avx512_1/libx264.so.160
```

For reference:

```
% apt-get source libc-bin
% cat sysdeps/x86/dl-procinfo.c | grep haswe
    "i586", "i686", "haswell", "xeon_phi"
% cat sysdeps/x86/dl-procinfo.c | grep avx
    "sse2", "x86_64", "avx512_1"
```

I've filled in a bug report for anyone interested:

- https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=1014536